# Windows: Auto close annoying popup (Logitech gaming software)

Tags: windows, vb.net, popup, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

So Logitech keyboard s/w engineers in all their wisdom decided to implement a popup ever time you switch an application that you have custom keyboard script mapping for. Meaning that you get this pop all the time when switching for explorer to chrome to desktop to whatever. I wrote to tek support and they said in the next update it'll be addressed though that was 3 months ago and I found ppl moaning to them about this F.ing feature for a over a year and a half.

So I wrote some code to kill it.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
    gtr; DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="FindWindowW" lesr;
    Public Shared Function FindWindowW(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpClassName As String, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
    gtr; DllImport("user32", EntryPoint:="SendMessageA", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError:=True, ExactSpelling:=True) lesr;
Public Shared Function SendMessageByString(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.VBByRefStr)> ByRef lParam As String) As Integer
    End Function
    Public Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = 274
    Public Const SC_CLOSE As Integer = 61536
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim hWnd As IntPtr = FindWindowW("Qt5QWindowToolSaveBits", "Logitech Gaming Software")
        If hWnd !== IntPtr.Zero Then
            Label1.Text = "Found"
            SendMessageByString(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0)
        Else
            Label1.Text = "Nothing"
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ShowInTaskbar = False
        NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
    End Sub
    Private Sub CloseToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseToolStripMenuItem.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

So nub of this is the timer runs every 200 ms and closes the window if it is there. And it works fine but surely, and I will call you Surely, there is a better way? As you can see its coded in VB net but a bit altered to get around the code tag mangaling. I feel that this code is causing some unwanted windows problems I have that I won't go into.

Ideas ppl?

Comment: If there's not service that can be stopped to disable this feature, you could run a process that uses UIAutomation's [WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.windowopenedevent) to detect when a new Window is opened, using e.g., its `ClassName` as filter to single it out, then get its `WindowPatter` and call the pattern [Close()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.close) method to close the Window. So *fire and forget*, no timers needed.

Comment: You can disable pop-up in LGS interface: Settings (gear icon, the second from the right) - Notifications (the second tab) - Profile change notification (the second check box)

Comment: Egor Skriptunoff -> Not in mine, my second tab is "Analytics"  and apparently I am running the "latest" ->

Software Version: 9.02.65
Last Update: 2018-10-08 <- !!!!!
OS: Windows 8, Windows 7, Windows 10
File Size: 123 MB

Comment: Jimi -> Thanks for the tip I'll give it a bash